# C# How to loop back to my first line of code in my calculator?

Tags: c#

Hello im trying to code a scientific calculator, im new to c# and im having some problems with trying to implement an option where at the end of a calculation I can ask the user whether they want to restart the calculator.

This is what i've got currently:

```
namespace Scientific_Calculator_Project
{
    class SuperCalculator
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Declaring my variables
            double num1, num2, answer;
            string operation;
            string exitOption;
            

            // Asking the user for the operation, to call a function to perform that operation
            Console.Write("Please enter an operation you wish to perform (+, -, /, *, ^, ^1/2, !, f-1): ");
            operation = Console.ReadLine();

            // Prompting the input of the first number
            Console.Write("Please enter your first number: ");
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            // Prompting the input of the second number
            Console.Write("Please enter your second number (if no other number is needed please enter ): ");
            num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


            // Using if statements to decide which function to call based on the operation, as well as an error message for an invalid value
            if (operation == "+")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Sum(num1, num2));
            }
            else if (operation == "-")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Minus(num1, num2));
            }
            else if (operation == "/")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Divide(num1, num2));
            }
            else if (operation == "*")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Multi(num1, num2));
            }
            else if (operation == "^")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ToPower(num1, num2));
            }

            else if (operation == "^1/2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Sqroot(num1));
            }
            else if (operation == "!")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Factorial(num1));
            }
            else if (operation == "f-1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ToInverse(num1));
            }
            else if (operation == "log")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ToLog(num1));
            }
            else if (operation == "rad")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ToRadian(num1)); 
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid operation");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to continue? (Yes/No)");
            exitOption = Console.ReadLine();
            
            

            Console.ReadLine();



            // Function for addition (Sum)
            static double Sum(double num1, double num2)
            {
                double resultofSum = num1 + num2;
                return resultofSum;
            }

            // Function for subtraction (Minus)
            static double Minus(double num1, double num2)
            {
                double resultofMinus = num1 - num2;
                return resultofMinus;
            }

            // Function for division (Divide)
            static double Divide(double num1, double num2)
            {
                double resultofDivide = num1 / num2;
                return resultofDivide;
            }

            // Function for multiplication (Multi)
            static double Multi(double num1, double num2)
            {
                double resultofMulti = num1 * num2;
                return resultofMulti;
            }

            // Function for raising x (num1) to the power of y (num2)
            static double ToPower(double num1, double num2)
            {
                double resultofToPower = Math.Pow(num1, num2);
                return resultofToPower;

            }

            // Function for square root of x (num1)
            static double Sqroot(double num1)
            {
                double resultofSqroot = Math.Sqrt(num1);
                return resultofSqroot;

            }
            
            // Function for finding factorial of x (num1),
            static double Factorial(double num1)
            {
                double factorial = 1;

                if (num1 < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Can't find factorial of a negative number");
                    return 0;
                }

                else if (num1 <= 1)
                {
                    return 1;
                }

                else
                {
                    for (double i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
                    {
                        factorial = factorial * i;

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}! = {1}", num1, factorial);
                    return factorial;
                }

            }

            // Function for obtaining the inverse of x (1/num1)
            static double ToInverse(double num1)
            {
                double ToInverse = 1 / num1;
                return ToInverse;
            }

            // Function for obtaining the base 10 log of x (num1)
            static double ToLog(double num1)
            {
                double Tolog = Math.Log10(num1);
                return Tolog;
            }

            // Function for converting an angle x (num1) from degrees to radians
            static double ToRadian(double num1)
            {
                double Toradian = (num1 * (Math.PI)) / 180;
                return Toradian;
            }

            



        }        
    }   
}
```

Comment: "how to loop"...by using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways, but here is an example of one way. The code below will loop each time the user hits a key, unless they hit the "Enter" key, in which case it will drop out and end:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
    bool loop = true;
    while (loop)
    {
        //do your stuff here
        //...

        //then do this:
        keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
        if(keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            loop = false;
        }
        else
        {
            loop = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem friend. If the answer is helpful please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the changes below

```
using System;

namespace Scientific_Calculator_Project
{
class SuperCalculator
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Declaring my variables
        double num1, num2, answer;
        string operation;
        string exitOption;

        while (true)
        {
            // Asking the user for the operation, to call a function to perform that operation
            Console.Write("Please enter an operation you wish to perform (+, -, /, *, ^, ^1/2, !, f-1): ");
            operation = Console.ReadLine();

            // Prompting the input of the first number
            Console.Write("Please enter your first number: ");
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            // Prompting the input of the second number
            Console.Write("Please enter your second number (if no other number is needed please enter ): ");
            num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


            // Using if statements to decide which function to call based on the operation, as well as an error message for an invalid value
            if (operation == "+")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Sum(num1, num2));
            }
            else if (operation == "-")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Minus(num1, num2));
            }
            else if (operation == "/")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Divide(num1, num2));
            }
            else if (operation == "*")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Multi(num1, num2));
            }
            else if (operation == "^")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ToPower(num1, num2));
            }

            else if (operation == "^1/2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Sqroot(num1));
            }
            else if (operation == "!")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Factorial(num1));
            }
            else if (operation == "f-1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ToInverse(num1));
            }
            else if (operation == "log")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ToLog(num1));
            }
            else if (operation == "rad")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ToRadian(num1));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid operation");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to continue? (Yes/No)");
            exitOption = Console.ReadLine();


            if(exitOption.ToLower() == "no")
            {
                break;
            }

           
            // Function for addition (Sum)
            static double Sum(double num1, double num2)
            {
                double resultofSum = num1 + num2;
                return resultofSum;
            }

            // Function for subtraction (Minus)
            static double Minus(double num1, double num2)
            {
                double resultofMinus = num1 - num2;
                return resultofMinus;
            }

            // Function for division (Divide)
            static double Divide(double num1, double num2)
            {
                double resultofDivide = num1 / num2;
                return resultofDivide;
            }

            // Function for multiplication (Multi)
            static double Multi(double num1, double num2)
            {
                double resultofMulti = num1 * num2;
                return resultofMulti;
            }

            // Function for raising x (num1) to the power of y (num2)
            static double ToPower(double num1, double num2)
            {
                double resultofToPower = Math.Pow(num1, num2);
                return resultofToPower;

            }

            // Function for square root of x (num1)
            static double Sqroot(double num1)
            {
                double resultofSqroot = Math.Sqrt(num1);
                return resultofSqroot;

            }

            // Function for finding factorial of x (num1),
            static double Factorial(double num1)
            {
                double factorial = 1;

                if (num1 < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: Can't find factorial of a negative number");
                    return 0;
                }

                else if (num1 <= 1)
                {
                    return 1;
                }

                else
                {
                    for (double i = 1; i <= num1; i++)
                    {
                        factorial = factorial * i;

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}! = {1}", num1, factorial);
                    return factorial;
                }

            }

            // Function for obtaining the inverse of x (1/num1)
            static double ToInverse(double num1)
            {
                double ToInverse = 1 / num1;
                return ToInverse;
            }

            // Function for obtaining the base 10 log of x (num1)
            static double ToLog(double num1)
            {
                double Tolog = Math.Log10(num1);
                return Tolog;
            }

            // Function for converting an angle x (num1) from degrees to radians
            static double ToRadian(double num1)
            {
                double Toradian = (num1 * (Math.PI)) / 180;
                return Toradian;
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: When i include the changes i get an error over the "break;" part, saying no enclosing loop out of which to break or continue